# Ctrl + Break does not interrupt execution

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Example:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
MsgBox "vbExclamation", vbExclamation
MsgBox "vbInformation", vbInformation
MsgBox "vbQuestion", vbQuestion
MsgBox "vbCritical", vbCritical
End Sub
```

Tried it with a different machine. Ctrl + Break worked well there.
On my machine it was like if I would press OK instead of Ctrl + Break

Comment: https://excelribbon.tips.net/T003906_Ctrl_Break_Wont_Work_to_Stop_a_Macro.html ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, method applies to Excel and apparently not Access.